# Resize windows by dragging around corner locaions?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can I enable the resize of my terminal by dragging in the general corner area.

Here's a video link of what I'm referring to.  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

https://youtu.be/Mkj338ytNPQ?t=3258

Some desktop info

```
sudo systemctl status display-manager

● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: en>
    Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/display-manager.service.d
             └─xdiagnose.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-10-09 11:00:48 EDT; 13h ago
    Process: 1800 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, sta>
    Process: 1803 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, sta>
   Main PID: 1804 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 19053)
     Memory: 7.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─1804 /usr/sbin/gdm3
```

and

```
env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
```

and

```
wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

Comment: That looks like a feature of KDE.  You do this by holding down `ALT`.  Right click is for resize and left click is for move. This is not a feature on GNOME

Comment: Well it works on MATE(ubuntu)... and I was just getting ready to type how I wished it worked inside of virtualbox guests.... But it does work on a MATE(ubuntu) guest, you have to hold the right CTRL and right ALT buttons while right-clicking... but yeah no such luck with gnome or MATE on centOS(which really sucks for me because I wanted this bad, those windows suck)... but thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Ubuntu Desktop, you achieve this by *right* clicking the window while you press down the "Window Action Key", which by default is the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. You will resize in any directions if you are close enough to a corner, otherwise you will resize the closest border you are pointing at.

You can change the window action key in Gnome Tweaks, Windows tab.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anything else I can try?

Comment: Then you may not have the default Ubuntu desktop? This is default behaviour.